Need to fix symlink with live usb
I have accidently made a wrong symlink
So currently rebooting does not work(giving error as image 1)
I am trying to solve this with a live usb mounted and creating a new symlink
But I cannot chroot because of the broken symlink. Is there a solution?
Can i just do the below command directly without chroot?
sudo ln -sf /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.35.so /mnt/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2



If you create the symlink like this:
sudo ln -sf /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.35.so /mnt/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Then, when the partition that's mounted at /mnt gets mounted elsewhere (say, /), it will still expect the link to be at /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.35.so. You should use either /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.35.so as the source, or use a relative path: ../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.35.so. I think the latter will be more resilient to mount point changes, but for a filesystem that's expected to be mounted at /, either is fine.

Yes, there is no need to chroot for that. I am guessing that you have mounted the local drive at /mnt, right? If so, all you need to do is:
sudo ln -sf /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.35.so /mnt/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

There is no need to chroot if all you need is to overwrite one symlink. You don't need the /dev stuff or anything else. This is a very simple operation at the file system level, nothing more complicated is needed.
